# How to prevent the conversion of text URL to link on a single URL?

Tags: 7, navigation

I have a page that I am adding, and for my purposes I want to have a text-only URL without an automatic link, but only for that one link, one this specific page. I need to be able to add full html content to the page, and I would prefer if other URLs on the page automatically became links.

I have tried putting other tags around the URL and HTML-escaping certain characters in the URL, but it still gets converted to a link.

Is there a way to prevent a specific URL from becoming a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I think it is possible to selectively disable the "Convert URLs into links" filter is to use CSS and add something like below to the body. Since CSS is applied client-side after Drupal has returned the page, the filter is effectively disabled for this one single link.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .mylink > span {
    display:none;
  }
  .mylink:after {
    content: 'http://www.google.com';
  }
</style>
<p class="mylink"><span>blah</span></p>
```

Since you are using the 'Full HTML' format, you should be able to add CSS directly into the body field like shown.

Comment: That's a creative idea. Nice. I'll take a look on Monday.

Comment: @mbomb007 Did this solve your issue?